# Filtering objects using a string input from search bar

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to make a filter/search function for items from 1 page only, so far I've tried many different methods and all of them did not work properly. I had the idea to search for a string through the whole page, the commented parts are my attempts to make it work, sadly I had no luck as of yet. I've tried array_search, but this is an object from what I understand, I had no luck with strpos too.

What I'm trying to do:

```
WP_User Object ( 
    [data] => stdClass Object ( 
        [ID] => 68 
        [user_login] => name 
        [user_pass] =>  
        [user_nicename] => name-nicename 
        [user_email] => name@mail.com 
        [user_url] =>asdf 
        [user_registered] => 2019 
        [user_activation_key] => 
        [user_status] => 0 
        [display_name] => KAROLIS DEDELE 
    ) 
    [ID] => 68 
    [caps] => Array ( [asdf] => 1 ) 
    [cap_key] => wp_capabilities 
    [roles] => Array ( [0] => ) 
    [allcaps] => Array ( 
        [edit_posts] => 1 
        [level_0] => 1 
        [read_private_events] => 1 
        [read_private_locations] => 1 
        [] => 1 
    ) 
    [filter] => 
    [site_id:WP_User:private] => 1 
)
```

I'm trying to get the `[display_name] => KAROLIS DEDELE` part.

here's the code which puts out all post parts. 
$str is the text which you enter in the search bar on the page. Other elements seem to be self explanatory.

```
$elements_list=array();

foreach($users as $user) {
    $show_user=0;
    //display_name => name surname
    if ($_GET) {
        if (isset($_GET[$user->roles[0]])) $show_user=1;
    } else $show_user=1;
    if ($show_user==1) {
        array_push($elements_list,array($user,0));
    }
    /*
    if ($user->$display_name == $str) {
        echo 'it works';
    else 'Sorry that user does not exist';
    }
    */
    //$display_names=array_search('display_name', $str);
    print_r($user);
    $organisation = get_user_meta($user->ID,$mv_org_name,true);
    if ($_GET) {
        if (!isset($_GET['organization'])) $set_organization=0;
    }
    if ($organisation!='' && $set_organization==1) {
        array_push($elements_list,array($user,1));
    }
    /*
    foreach ($user as $display_name) {
        $found=0;
        if($display_name == $str){
            $show_user=1;
            $found=1;
            if($found==1){
                echo $str,' found ';
            }
            //print_r($display_name);
        }
        else {
            $show_user=0;
            echo ' nerasta ';
            //print_r($str);
        }
    }
    */
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong, or maybe the functions I'm using are incorrect

Comment: This looks right. 
if ($user->display_name == $str) {
        echo 'it works';
    else 'Sorry that user does not exist';
    }
But are you searching for characters in string or must match all?

Comment: I'm looking for characters in string. On the webpage there are people blocks with names and surnames placed in a grid pattern, so the search bar would filter names and/or surnames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you're doing wrong is that you access the wrong data in the wrong way. You should do it by searching against `$user->data->display_name` instead of `$user->$display_name`.

Also, you may use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) instead of a loop:

```
$elements_list = array_filter($users, static function(WP_User $user) use ($str, $mv_org_name) {
    if (!empty($str) && stripos($user->data->display_name, $str) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!empty($_GET)) {
        if (!isset($_GET[$user->roles[0]]) {
             return false;
        }

        if ((int) ($_GET['organization'] ?? 0) === 1 && 
            get_user_meta($user->ID, $mv_org_name, true) === ''
        ) {
             return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
});
```